# How to make the div with delay and easing effect

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I tried to show the div with delay on page load also with easing effect I tried this one to make that div as easing effect after the page load(5 sec) that div appear properly but it is not in easing effect. I am not sure how to make the easing effect here.
Here is the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Fx5pL/)

**jQuery:**

```
jQuery('.bar_b_message').hide(0).delay(5000).show(0)
                        .slideDown(5000, 'easeOutBounce');
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="bar_builder">
    <div class="bar_b_message">This is for testing.</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Use callback functions

Comment: @Ikac: what would be the point of using callback function to do something simple like this ?

Comment: Callback can do that `easing effect` u start with showing on start and when all is 100% callback is triggered like return.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should remove the ".show()". The slideDown method will take care of displaying the div.

So please try this:

```
jQuery('.bar_b_message').hide(0).delay(5000).slideDown(5000, 'easeOutBounce');
```

Comment: Please note my answer as solution by clicking on the big gray "check" icon below the vote count. This way, people will know that this is a working solution. Thanks.

Comment: _Please note my answer as solution by clicking on the big gray "check" icon below the vote count_. I ready to accept the answer once you posted but unfortunately SO says you could wait 8 minutes to accept the answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try this

Html (same as yours)

```
<div class="bar_builder">
   <div class="bar_b_message">This is for testing.</div>
</div>
```

jQuery

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.bar_b_message').delay(5000).slideDown(5000, 'easeOutBounce');
});
```

CSS

```
.bar_b_message{ display: none; }
```

CSS hides the div initially. On load, the jQuery pauses for 5 seconds then slides the div down (slideDown also sets the div 'display' property to 'block')